# A one time error breaks subsequent usage of Entity framework

Tags: ef-code-first, autofac, lifecycle, entity-framework-5

We have a problem with entity framework. For example if we do:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

and then we try to delete an entity that has mapped child entities who depend on it, it is logical that we get an error. (Cannot delete parent when there are children in database that depend on it).

Afterwards, using a new context instance, doing a 'ParentEntity.ChildEntities.ToList()' there is still a problem!

A workaround is to restart the app pool, and the problem goes away.

We are using Autofac and the lifecycle of the context is set (and confirmed) to per HttpRequest, so the error persists somewhere else. Any idea what can be done so as to avoid these errors?

Our guess is that the objectcontext is persistent somewhere else, and it stores the state of the child entities as "EntityState.Deleted" so this conflicts with the actual data received from the database on subsequent calls.

**Update:** Seems like a closer examination of the stack reveals that there is a lazy internal context:

```
[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.]
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +200
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +33
    System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20
```

Maybe if I were to somehow disable LazyInternalContext? Can this be done?

Comment: Does "*Afterwards...*" mean: In a new request (= new context instance)?

Comment: That means, in the new context instance you load the parent and the children, then delete the parent again and you get the same error, right? If so, the error is not surprising if you don't delete the children at the same time and cascading delete is disabled for the relationship.

Comment: No, on the subsequent load we just load the parent and enumerate through the children for example, on a completely different part of code.

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you get an exception when you iterate through the children and what exception?

Comment: There is no particular exception, the list is just empty. For example while iterating through an .Aggregate() it throws 'Sequence contains no elements'

Comment: I see, and you guess that the list is empty because the children are still in `Deleted` state, right? You could check the content of the context before you load entities and start the iteration: `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()`. If the context is really a new instance, it should be empty. There is no other storage of entity states except in the context instance itself and they do not move from one instance to another.

Comment: You see, the problem is not the persistance of the ChangeTracker objects or not. The problem is the persistance of an error (may it be COMPLETELY different from any further operation). This means: I get an error, and then no operations whatsoever can be completed unless I restart the application itself. Even a simple `.ToList()`

Comment: Well, the persistence of change tracker entries might cause the persistence of the error if the entries are in an invalid state. It would mean of course that the context isn't correctly disposed and recreated between requests. An example of the code you are using in the first and second request that causes the error could help.

Comment: I have repositories that share a context, which is created per http request. Using debugging and inspecting the context reveals that it is a fresh copy each time - I even added an arbitrary property to it in order to double check. Entries are not persisting, only the error (somewhere, somehow) persists.

Comment: What is exactly the problem, is it with getting the Exception after removing the convention or what ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem? We have the exact samme issue: if a save in EF somehow fails in a request - all other saves will fail in subsequent requests. When I debug on localhost, I can see that a new context is created on each request. Furthermore, the context is disposed at the end of each request. So how can the error state of some entities still be persisted in the context?

Comment: I have actually moved all my projects to use NHibernate due to it being more mature and extensible. I haven't goneback to EF for a while

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get the exceptions and keep the database in a valid state by your self for some reason you can do so by stopping validation:

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; // you can put this in the constructor of your context;
context.SaveChanges();
```